# ElasticSearch - creating exceptions for fuzzy terms

Tags: elasticsearch, search, fuzzy-search

I have simple elastic query that does a simple text field search with the fuziness distance of one:

```
GET /jobs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "attributes.title": {
        "value": "C#"
        "fuzziness": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above query does exactly what it is told to do, but I have a cases where I don't want a word to resolve (with fuzziness) to another specific word. In this case, I don't want `C#` to also return `C++` results. Similarly I don't want `cat` to return `car` results.

However I do still need the fuzziness option if someone did actually misspelled `cat`. In that case it can return results of both `cat` and `car`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is possible with some bool query combination, it should be something like this:

```
bool:
    //should
        //match query without fuzzy
        //bool
            //must 
                //must with fuzzy query 
                //must_not with match query
```

Comment: Trying to see if this works. I understand your approach. No need for full example.

Comment: This solution works fine. Although I would have liked an approach similar to how synonyms are defined. Guess it is not possible :) Thank you!